# Why is EE not autosaving?

Tags: channel-entries, config

I have got editors who often have an entry open around 30minutes before saving.
I have turned on autosaving in the config.php file and this is also reflected in the config edotr in the control panel:

```
$config['autosave_interval_seconds'] = '5'; // to test I have set this to 5 seconds 
$config['autosave_prune_hours'] = '8';
```

I have tried to research this problem but I can't find anything helpful.

Am using ExpressionEngine v2.5.2 (this is a multi site).

Any help is appreciated,
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can see no one answered this for you. I'm having issues with autosave, maybe my explanation about how it works will answer your question. Maybe the issue I'm having is the same?

[autosave does not work as expected. Specifically RTE and WYGWAM](https://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/questions/14823/autosave-does-not-work-as-expected-specifically-rte-and-wygwam)

Comment: Thank you for this. It was very frustrating and confusing and nice to at least know that there is a problem.

Comment: No problem. At least it's a confirmed bug. I have the feeling as the feature was badly implemented from the beginning many devs turn it off. Which in turn meant P&T had little desire to account for it. I'm hoping this feature get's some love as it's a real plus for clients.